# Div Class order Problems

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a social media network, and in my posts, I am trying to add the glyphicons found in Bootstrap 3 to the posts. Now, I have managed to the the icons on the same line as the username, but I can't work out how to get the username first, and then the glyphicons. Below is my code:

```
<div class="media well single-post" id="post-<?php echo $post['post_id'];?>">

<div class="avatar large pull-left">
    <?php if ($this->profile_type === 'page' || $post['post_wall_profile_type'] === 'page'):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/<?php echo $post['post_wall_name'];?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->GetStorageUrl('avatar') . $post['post_wall_avatar'];?>">
    </a>
    <?php elseif ($this->profile_type === 'feed' && $post['post_wall_profile_type'] === 'group'):?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/<?php echo $post['post_wall_name'];?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->GetStorageUrl('avatar') . $post['post_wall_avatar'];?>">
    </a>
    <?php else:?>
    <div class="pull-right"><?php if (isset($post['author_meta']['badges'])):?>
        <div class="network-badges vertical">
            <?php echo $this->partial('/partial/badges.phtml', array('badges' => $post['author_meta']['badges']));?>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?><div class="pull-left"><a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/<?php echo $post['user_name'];?>"></div></div>
        <div class="pull-left"><img src="<?php echo $this->GetStorageUrl('avatar') . $post['user_avatar'];?>">
    </a></div>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Here is what it currently looks like: http://www.startrekrisa.com/Picture1.png

I know it's gonna be a simple fix, but I cannot work out how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you adding the glyph-icons? I can't see them in the code you posted.

Comment: The code is: <div class="pull-right"><?php if (isset($post['author_meta']['badges'])):?>
   <div class="network-badges vertical">
    <?php echo $this->partial('/partial/badges.phtml', array('badges' => $post['author_meta']['badges']));?>
   </div>
   <?php endif;?><div class="pull-left"><a href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/<?php echo $post['user_name'];?>"></div></div>

Comment: OK, but I don't see any HTML class or anything for the glyph-icons.

Comment: This is the actual badge code I have got: <?php if (isset($post['author_meta']['badges'])):?>
   <div class="network-badges vertical">
    <?php echo $this->partial('/partial/badges.phtml', array('badges' => $post['author_meta']['badges']));?>
   </div>

Comment: OK. Can you show the relevant code for `/partial/badges.phtml`, please?

Comment: <?php 


if ($this->badges && $this->badges){
 
 $badges_array = explode(",", $this->badges);
}

if (isset($badges_array) && !empty($badges_array)){
 foreach ($badges_array as $badge){
  echo '<span class="network-badge glyphicon glyphicon-'.trim($badge).'" title="'.$this->translate(trim($badge)).'"></span>';
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

*[Edit] See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8Pjd/2/) based on the fixed markup below and the `/partial/badges.phtml` code you gave in a comment; obviously your global css is not there, but you can see it properly puts the avatar left and the glyphicons to the right of it [/Edit]*

The HTML you generate with that piece of code doesn't seem quite right, and considering your question only relates to html/css, it would have been better to strip your code sample down to a piece of html+css, without the php logic.

From what I can see, your question directlly concern the *else* part of your main logic, when the inner *if* is true. In that case I believe your code will generate

```
<div class="media well single-post" id="post-1234">
    <div class="avatar large pull-left">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="network-badges vertical">
                <!-- content of /partial/badges.phtml with the user bages -->
            </div>
            <div class="pull-left"><a href="http://example.org/users/username"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left"><img src="http://example.org/avatars/username">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see here you have html problems:

1. your *pull-left* div is closed before the link inside is closed; the link inside is closed further on
2. you have a mismatch between open and close tags for your *div*

I believe the html you'd want would be more like

```
<div class="media well single-post" id="post-1234">
    <div class="avatar large pull-left">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="network-badges vertical">
                <!-- content of /partial/badges.phtml with the user bages -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">
            <a href="http://example.org/users/username">
                <img src="http://example.org/avatars/username">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mixing php logic with your html like that is not terrific and will lead you to more similar problems where you end up not generating the markup you imagined.

P.S. It usually a good practice when working on the interface to first work without any logic behind and just static data, to ensure you get the markup you want and need, and then only merge this with your logic (but it's still better to have your logic separated from the ui though)